# Missing documentation for Firebase.auth in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I noticed that documentation about `Firebase.auth` is not available in Android Studio:

[image]
Why is that? How to get documentation directly in Android Studio? It seems only to affect `Firebase.auth`, not everything from Firebase. My app `build.gradle.kts` looks like this:

```
// Import the Firebase BoM
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.2"))

// See https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
// For example, add the dependencies for Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
```

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow is the right place to post this.  It's likely a problem with the Firebase SDK and should be reported to Firebase directly.  Perhaps you could try [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk) or [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).